# Javascript ES6 sorting by same content

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hello when I use on array of objects

```
const myArray = [{id: "C", grade: "bad", name: "John"},
{id: "A", grade: "good", name: "Peter"},
{id: "A", grade: "good", name: "Lucia"},
{id: "B", grade: "average", name: "Thomas"}]
```

this function

```
const groupedReactions = myArray.reduce(
  (entryMap, e) => entryMap.set(e.id, [...(entryMap.get(e.id) || []), e]),
  new Map()
);
```

I can get here

```
Map {
 'A' => [ { id: 'A', grade: 'good', name: 'Peter' }, { id: 'A', grade: 'good', name: 'Lucia' } ],
 'B' => [ { id: 'B', grade: 'average', name: 'Thomas' } ],
 'C' => [ { id: 'C', grade: 'bad', name: 'John' } ] }
```

but I would like to see this output

```
{
  "A": [{name:"Peter"},{name:"Lucia"}],
  "B": [{name:"Thomas"}], 
  "C": [{name:"John"}]
}
```

can you help me how to modify the function? 
or should I use a new one? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Destructure the object, and take only the properties you need using rest syntax (`...`). Convert the Map to an object with `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const myArray = [{"id":"C","grade":"bad","name":"John"},{"id":"A","grade":"good","name":"Peter"},{"id":"A","grade":"good","name":"Lucia"},{"id":"B","grade":"average","name":"Thomas"}]

const groupedReactions = Object.fromEntries(myArray.reduce(
  (entryMap, { id, grade, ...e}) => entryMap.set(id, [...(entryMap.get(id) || []), e]),
  new Map()
))

console.log(groupedReactions)
```

Instead of reducing to Map, and then converting to an object, you can reduce to an object:

```js
const myArray = [{"id":"C","grade":"bad","name":"John"},{"id":"A","grade":"good","name":"Peter"},{"id":"A","grade":"good","name":"Lucia"},{"id":"B","grade":"average","name":"Thomas"}]

const groupedReactions = myArray.reduce(
  (r, { id, grade, ...e}) => {
    if(!r[id]) r[id] = []
    
    r[id].push(e)
    
    return r
  },
  {}
)

console.log(groupedReactions)
```

Comment: wau, this looks great just one question 
if I will reduce to the object how I can get to the object "name" instead of "grade"? I have grade there now :/
I have to understand the code line by line :D

Comment: Just switch `name` with `grade` because properties that appear before the `...` will not be included in the output object (`e`). Updated the answer.

Comment: We destructure `id` and `grade` out, and collect the rest in an object (`e`). If there's no value under `id`, set it as an empty array. Always push the current `e` to an array under its original `id` property.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Is not better to get `"A": ["Peter","Lucia"],` instead `"A": [{name:"Peter"},{name:"Lucia"}],`? You will find the two solutions:

```js
const myArray = [{id: "C", grade: "bad", name: "John"},
{id: "A", grade: "good", name: "Peter"},
{id: "A", grade: "good", name: "Lucia"},
{id: "B", grade: "average", name: "Thomas"}]

const note = {};
myArray.forEach((student) => {
  const key = student.id
  if (!note[key])
    note[key] = []
  note[key].push(student.name) // or: .push({name: student.name})
});

console.log(note);
```

Comment: this looks easiest to understand... yes I can consider to have only array of names good point :) now I want to continue and get string: "good x 2 (Peter, Lucia) – average (Thomas) - bad (John)" I am thinking my logic was bad and for this is better to produce this   
`{ "good": ["Peter","Lucia"], "average": ["Thomas"], "bad": ["John"] }`
what is easy to make with your code

Comment: You can convert the key like this: `const convert = {A:"good", B:"average",C:"bad"};` and then: `const key = convert[student.id]`